# Sending multiple options via "--push-option=" in "git push"

Tags: git, git-push

With **Git 2.10** a new option came [[--push-option=]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#git-push---push-option). When a bare repository is created a **post-receive.sample** is auto created inside hooks directory, which saying following:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to make use of push options.
# The example simply echoes all push options that start with 'echoback='
# and rejects all pushes when the "reject" push option is used.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "pre-receive".
```

I tried following steps

1. Renaming the file to pre-receive
2. Clone the repository to a local machine
3. tried `git push --push-option=echoback=Hello_world`

As the sample says it put back the `Hello_world` in my terminal.

[Git Hook Manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive) says that i could send multiple options via `--push-option=` which will be available via `GIT_PUSH_OPTION_0, GIT_PUSH_OPTION_1,...` as the manual suggests.

**My Question is How should i pass multiple options ? which could be passed via** `--push-option=`

Tried options:

1. `git push --push-option="echoback=Hello echoback=World"`
2. `git push --push-option="echoback=Hello;echoback=World"`
3. `git push --push-option="echoback=Hello&echoback=World"`
4. `git push --push-option="echoback=Hello%echoback=World"`
5. `git push --push-option="echoback=Hello,echoback=World"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

`git push --push-option="echoback=Hello" --push-option="echoback=World"`

This seperates the `--push-option`s

Comment: i forgot to mention about comma, comma wasn't working

Comment: `git push --push-option="echoback=Hello" --push-option="echoback=World"`

This trick does the work :) (Y)

Comment: stack says i can accept it 4 minutes later, by the do you find this way in any documentation of brute forced it ?

Comment: Actully just guessed!

Comment: How about you edit the comment and remove the 4 minute part since that wont be helpful in the uture.

Comment: Edit option is gone, only delete is available.

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.15.x/2.16 (Q1 2018) clarifies the multiple push-options usage, adding the "`--push-option=<string>`" option to "`git push`" now defaults to a list of strings configured via `push.pushOption` variable.

So you can either use multiple push options:

```
git push --push-option="a" --push-option="b"
```

Or use multiple configuration string

```
~/.gitconfig
  push.pushoption = a
  push.pushoption = b
```

See [commit d805275](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8052750c5fdd53cb5a664a18ce9d78dbedb22ae) (23 Oct 2017) by [Marius Paliga (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c692fe2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c692fe2c1e3b0104c5573e2ec3ae62ba2711c4e6), 06 Nov 2017)</sup>

> `builtin/push.c`: add `push.pushOption` config
>
> Push options need to be given explicitly, via the command line as "`git push --push-option <option>`".
>   Add the config option `push.pushOption`, which is a multi-valued option, containing push options that are sent by default.
>
> When push options are set in the lower-priority configulation file
>   (e.g. `/etc/gitconfig`, or `$HOME/.gitconfig`), they can be unset later in
>   the more specific repository config by the empty string.